# Solve $y'\sin x = y\ln y , y\left( \tfrac{\pi}{2} \right) = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$y'\sin x = y\ln y ,\quad y\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr) = 1$$

Final answer has to be: $y = 1$

I've tried by doing this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget the constant of integration; you end up with:
$$\ln \left|\ln y\right| = \ln \left|\tan\frac{x}{2}\right| + \color{red}{C} \implies\ln y = \color{blue}{c} \tan\frac{x}{2} \implies y = e^{\color{blue}{c}\tan\frac{x}{2}}$$
with $\color{blue}{c}=\pm e^\color{red}{C}$. Then $y\left( \tfrac{\pi}{2} \right) = 1$ gives you:
$$1 = e^{c\tan\tfrac{\pi}{4}} \iff 1 = e^c \iff c = 0$$

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: "Don't forget the constant of integration" ...Indeed, and don't forget the absolute values either -- which I added. +1.

Comment: +1 for the comment/edit. OP had that part right and I was lazy, but that's a bad excuse! :)

Comment: Interestingly, solving the differential equation is not even needed to answer this question. To see why, consider any separable differential equation $$y'=f(y)g(x)$$ and some $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $f(y_0)=0$, then, if Cauchy-Lipschitz hypotheses are met at $(x_0,y_0)$, then the solution such that $y(x_0)=y_0$  exists an is unique hence it is $y(x)=y_0$ for every $x$. (Here, $f(y)=y\ln y$ and $y_0=1$ hence indeed $f(y_0)=0$. Furthermore, $g(x)=1/\sin x$ and $x_0=\pi/2$ hence the argument applies at least to every $x$ in $(0,\pi)$.)